# Getting results from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables and I would like to show it's contents by using `WHERE client=1234` and `ORDER BY date ASC`.

Table `docs_data_invoices i`:

```
id, date, client, invoice, amount
```

Table `docs_data_payments p`:

```
id, date, client, currency, amount
```

The results must be like this:

```
i.date, i.invoice, i.amount, p.date, p.client, p.currency, p.amount
```

That's what I've tried:

```
SELECT i.date, i.invoice, i.amount, p.date, p.client, p.currency, p.amount FROM docs_data_invoices i JOIN docs_data_payments p ON i.client=p.client WHERE i.client=1234 ORDER BY i.date ASC
```

But it returns strange results:

[image]

The main idea is to see all invoices and payments, ordered by date.

Comment: [JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).

Comment: Yes, I'm trying with `JOIN` but I can't do it... it gives me strange results (identical values from the both tables).

Comment: then show the query you tried to use. We're not here to write code for you - we just try to fix things that YOU have attempted.

Comment: If you really want our input then post the code you tried A.S.A.P. Otherwise your question will be closed pretty quick.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the results you want here because you're not capturing the necessary data.  Clients should make payments against an invoice (so the payments table should have a foreign key to the invoice id, which it doesn't.)

Right now all you can determine is that the client has invoices and that the client made payments, but there isn't really any reason to join the two tables.

Comment: Yeah, maybe that's why it's not working. Anyway, I'll make it on two queries and I'll mix the result. The main idea is to see all invoices and payments, ordered by date.